# Using cxxreact to generate views?

Tags: c++, react-native

I've been looking at the `cxxreact` examples e.g. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactCommon/cxxreact/SampleCxxModule.cpp. I can see the obvious purpose is to have performant native code that handles data processing. I'm wondering if it might also be possible to use C++ here to generate views, e.g. via OpenGL?

I'm currently using a C++ library to handle audio processing and custom graphics. It already uses OpenGL to draw onto either a UIView (iOS) or View/ViewGroup (Android). Rather than having to go via the platform's bridge, and all the extra platform-specific setup that requires (ViewManagers etc) it would be great to be able to do this all in C++. Are there any examples of this around?